# SP2010 Calendar workflow to send a form after each event

Tags: workflow, calendar

I want an workflow to see if the event ended yesterday, if so, then start a task process to ask if the event was cancelled.  If it was cancelled, then remove from the calendar list.  Else step two provide a form for the rtask recipient to fill in.

Haveing trouble creating a calculated field to determine if the events end date was yesterday.

Any offerings of help with this work flow?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to start a workflow in such a manner. The only start options are manually (click on it), when an item is created or when an item is changed.

Timer checking workflows require code on the server.

One way around this is to have the workflow execute on item creation and pause until the event date + 1 day and then use an if statement to check for the cancellation or send the form. The problem with this method is if you change dates on the event it won't run at the right time. More convoluted logic (including parallel blocks) can be used to compensate but it starts to get really messy.

Comment: I created a workflow on a calendar list to start manually, new item, or item change. Pause until end time +1 then send task to update the Tele Conference information.  My issue is in how to handle recurring events as the start and end dates  don't match each event in the series.  Just the start of the first event and the end of the last event in the series.

Comment: This does not work with recurring events. Those are actually handled quite strangely by SharePoint.